# Is "zoom" CSS property safe to use with mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, css, mobile, responsive-design

I know its used to trigger hasLayout in old IE's but is it safe to use with mobile devices to zoom in/out the viewport that is set in HTML with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

`zoom` property seems to work pretty well in most of the browsers, even old androids e.g. 2.2 but are there any possible problems I need to know before using this property to zoom in/out the page content?

Comment: Please accept the answer as true to provide our community with an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Zoom is awesome

Unless you're targeting folk that live in the days of Gingerbread, Apple, Android, and even Windows supports this feature.

In all likelihood (assuming I don't know the rest of your code), you will still need to set your `viewports`, but for a single mobile/desktop environment you're on the right path.

#### Here's a great article to wrap your head around it:

- http://html5hacks.com/blog/2012/11/28/elegantly-resize-your-page-with-the-at-viewport-css-declaration/